# 500 internal server error occurs when i tried to sen JSON encoded array to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have write the following code and I'm facing

"500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:4"

error

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('‪#‎vehicle_no‬').blur(function(){
      $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: '/autolube/Invoices/fetchData',
              data: {value: $('#vehicle_no').val()},
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data) {
                   $('‪#‎name‬').val(data.Name);
                   $('‪#‎address‬').val(data.Address);
                   $('‪#‎promotions‬').val(data.Promotion);
                   $('‪#‎incentives‬').val(data.Incentive);
                 }
            });
    });
});
```

And fetchDaya() is

```
 public function fetchData(){

   if ($this->request->is('post')) {

       $this->layout = 'ajax';
       $this->autoRender = false;
       $user= $this->Invoice->User->findByVehicleNo($_POST['value']);
       if($user)
       {
         $name = $user['User']['first_name'];
         $name = $name." ".$user['User']['last_name'];
         $address = $user['User']['address'];
         $promotion = $this->Invoice->Promotion->findById($user['User']['promotion_id']);
         $incentive = $this->Invoice->Incentive->findById($user['User']['incentive_id']);
         $data= array('Name'=>$name, 'Address' => $address, 'Promotion' =>$promotion, 'Incentive' =>$incentive);
         echo json_encode($data);

       }



   }

 }
```

if i do the following changes it works fine

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#vehicle_no').blur(function(){
      $.ajax({
         type: "post",
         url: '/autolube/Invoices/fetchData',
         data: {value: $('#vehicle_no').val()},
         success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
            }

        });

   });
});
```

and

```
public function fetchData(){

   if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $user= $this->Invoice->User->findByVehicleNo($_POST['value']);
          if($user)
            {
                   $name = $user['User']['first_name'];
                   $name = $name." ".$user['User']['last_name'];
                   echo $name;

            }

         }

    }
```

I'm unable to find the solution for this problem.

Comment: I'm not a PHP person, but I'm guessing you might've made a mistake in the last 5 lines of that if loop in your PHP code.

Comment: 500 Internal is a server side error, and since you tried without the last 5 lines, there should be an error there, try testing each one, until you get the error, and then fix, don't forget to try the last one and use the json type in the jquery. Another way is calling directly the page in the browser, and use GET (instead of POST just for test purposes) in the code, provide the value as a parameter in the url and check which line is throwing the error.

Comment: What happens if you replace `$this->Invoice->Promotion` with `$this->Invoice->User->Promotion` and do the same for Incentive? (If you are sure this is not the right syntax, no need to try, I'm just guessing)

Answer (score 1):

Because of my reputation I cannot add a comment so here it goes. I believe it is a problem at your fetchData() function as I is an internal server error. Try to test this function, specially at:

```
$promotion = $this->Invoice->Promotion->findById($user['User']['promotion_id']);
$incentive = $this->Invoice->Incentive->findById($user['User']['incentive_id']);
```

And make sure that it isn't crashing there.